# use single ng-repeat scope in multiple div's in page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to use **ng-repeat** scope value in multiple div's. I'm using **pagination** for one repeat scope on single page.

This is my code

```
<div>
    <div align="left">
        <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1"></button> 
    </div>
    <div  ng-repeat="projects in allProjects | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" >
        <h2 class="text-light" ng-show="allProjects.length">
            {{projects.projectName}}
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div  align="right">
        <button  ng-disabled="currentPage >= allProjects.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1"></button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row chart-size" ng-repeat="projects in allProjects | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
   //chart
</div>

<div ng-repeat="projects in allProjects | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" >
    <h2 class="text-light" align="center" ng-show="allProjects.length">
                <font color="red" >{{projects.overAll}}%</font>

    </h2>
</div>
```

my page limit is 1.This works fine for me.But not sure this is proper solution. How to use properly this case.

Comment: okayi am not really sure but if u have your $scope value in your controller you could either let all pages run within the same controller if you show the same data or you $rootScope which is not the best way

Comment: thanks for response. you know any other approach for this.

Comment: Well if you are using the $stateprovider you have your different states where you can specify which controller is used for which view for example .state('login', {
        params: 8,
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: "LoginCtrl"
  }) here is a link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router